# Why is my LOGCAT in Android Studio constantly logging?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, android-virtual-device, logcat

Trying to come to terms with writing an Android plugin for Unity, and the LOGCAT in my Android Studio is constantly logging error and warnings with an idle virtual device. I've never really used LOGCAT before, so I have no idea if this is normal behavior. Two errors pop up when I launch a virtual device however.

[image]

LOGCAT:

```
1985-1985/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
1988-1988/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
3119-3428/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #startMicroDetector [speakerMode: 0]
3119-3428/? W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 393244, bug: 0]: errorCode: 393244, engine: 0
3119-3428/? I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
3119-3428/? I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
1858-1858/? W/adbd: timeout expired while flushing socket, closing
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
1837-2398/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
```

Then it keeps repeating the lines from "I/MicroDetectionWorker" to "E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface" over and over.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much normal behaviour for logcat as it logs anything going on in your system. To reduce the amount of noise being logged you can use a filter like `adb logcat -s Unity PackageManager dalvikvm DEBUG`. This will pretty much filter out anything not unity related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOGCAT is a system log, it logs stacks, errors, and app's messages like for debugging. So it's not just your app, its the whole system. Many malware uses this to get data about you and your phone, be careul with what you log on it.

And in your case apparently it can't find a mic.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about malware.